# samhoche.net mirroring SO with ads

Tags: discussion

I was searching for an answer via Google and in the top 5 (under the real thing) was yet another mirror site:

(Enter at your own expense, there were some popups and such but might contain something worse)
http://www.samhohce.net/questions/ *actual question url*

Needless to say that it's shady at best.

Comment: I had to use Siri to escape those ads.

Comment: I does not even work for me...